# Memory leaks in Gluon/JavaFXPorts running on iOS

Tags: memory-leaks, robovm, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

After porting our app with Gluon to iOS we noticed that is runs very slowly in the simulator as well as on real devices (in my case iPad 3 running iOS7).
We used profiling tools provided by XCode to examine possible reasons and found some memory leaks.
Then we tried a basic Gluon project (Single View, empty) and found the same memory leaks.
I am neither an expert with RoboVM nor with JavaFXPorts/Gluon so I don't know where to look. But I could provide more information when you tell me what you need.

I appreciate any help and any other suggestions how to make the app more responsive and faster because the memory leaks seem to be just a part of the problem.

Here is the memory leak stacktrace provided by XCode for a basic HelloWorld Application:

```
   Bytes Used   # Leaks     Symbol Name\  

8.72 KB      86.5%  62      start\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62       main\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62        rvmRun\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62         rvmCallVoidClassMethod\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62          rvmCallVoidClassMethodA\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62           callVoidMethod\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62            _call0\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62             [J]org.javafxports.jfxmobile.ios.BasicLauncher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62              [j]org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62               [J]org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                [J]org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(ILorg/robovm/rt/bro/ptr/BytePtr$BytePtrPtr;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                 UIApplicationMain\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                  GSEventRunModal\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                   CFRunLoopRunInMode\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                    CFRunLoopRunSpecific\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                     __CFRunLoopRun\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                      __CFRunLoopDoSources0\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                       __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                        __NSThreadPerformPerform\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                         -[GlassRunnable run]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                          CallVoidMethod\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                           rvmCallVoidInstanceMethodA\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                            callVoidMethod\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                             _call0\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                              [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run()V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                               [j]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)V[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                 [j]java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                  [J]java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                   [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run()Ljava/lang/Object;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                    [j]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Void;[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                     [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Void;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                      [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run()V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                       [j]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch;)V[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                        [J]com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                         [J]com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run()V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                          [j]com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean;Ljavafx/application/Application;)V[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                           [J]com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean;Ljavafx/application/Application;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                            [J]com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(Ljavafx/stage/Stage;)V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                             [j]java.lang.String.format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                              [J]java.lang.String.format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                               [J]java.lang.String.format(Ljava/util/Locale;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                [J]java.util.Formatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Formatter;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                 [J]java.util.Formatter.format(Ljava/util/Locale;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Formatter;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                  [j]libcore.icu.LocaleData.get(Ljava/util/Locale;)Llibcore/icu/LocaleData;[clinit]\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                   _bcInitializeClass\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                    rvmInitialize\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                     _call0\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                      [J]libcore.icu.LocaleData.<clinit>()V\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                       [J]libcore.icu.LocaleData.get(Ljava/util/Locale;)Llibcore/icu/LocaleData;\  
8.72 KB      86.5%  62                                                        [J]libcore.icu.LocaleData.initLocaleData(Ljava/util/Locale;)Llibcore/icu/LocaleData;\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                         [j]libcore.icu.ICU.getBestDateTimePattern(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;[clinit]\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                          [J]libcore.icu.ICU.getBestDateTimePattern(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                           [J]libcore.icu.ICU.getBestDateTimePatternNative(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                            Java_libcore_icu_ICU_getBestDateTimePatternNative\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                             icu_51::DateTimePatternGenerator::createInstance(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
7.31 KB      72.5%  52                                                              icu_51::DateTimePatternGenerator::DateTimePatternGenerator(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                               icu_51::DateTimePatternGenerator::initData(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                icu_51::DateTimePatternGenerator::addICUPatterns(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                 icu_51::DateFormat::create(icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::Locale const&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                  icu_51::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                   icu_51::SimpleDateFormat::construct(icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                    icu_51::SimpleDateFormat::initialize(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                     icu_51::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu_51::Locale const&, UNumberFormatStyle, signed char, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                      icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::DecimalFormatSymbols(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                       icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char)\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                        ures_open_51\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                         malloc\  
6.47 KB      64.1%  46                                                                          malloc_zone_malloc\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                icu_51::DateTimePatternGenerator::setDecimalSymbols(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                 icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::DecimalFormatSymbols(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                  icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char)\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                   ures_open_51\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                    malloc\  
 864 Bytes    8.3%  6                                                                     malloc_zone_malloc\  
1.41 KB      13.9%  10                                                         [j]libcore.icu.ICU.initLocaleDataNative(Ljava/lang/String;Llibcore/icu/LocaleData;)Z[clinit]\  
1.41 KB      13.9%  10                                                          [J]libcore.icu.ICU.initLocaleDataNative(Ljava/lang/String;Llibcore/icu/LocaleData;)Z\  
1.41 KB      13.9%  10                                                           Java_libcore_icu_ICU_initLocaleDataNative\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                             icu_51::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu_51::Locale const&, UNumberFormatStyle, signed char, UErrorCode&)\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                              icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::DecimalFormatSymbols(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                               icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char)\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                                ures_open_51\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                                 malloc\  
1.12 KB      11.1%  8                                                                  malloc_zone_malloc\  
 288 Bytes    2.7%  2                                                             icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::DecimalFormatSymbols(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)\  
 288 Bytes    2.7%  2                                                              icu_51::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu_51::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char)\  
 288 Bytes    2.7%  2                                                               ures_open_51\  
 288 Bytes    2.7%  2                                                                malloc\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5       thread_start\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5        _pthread_start\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5         _pthread_body\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5          GC_start_routine\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5           GC_call_with_stack_base\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5            GC_inner_start_routine\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5             startThreadEntryPoint\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5              rvmCallVoidInstanceMethodA\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5               callVoidMethod\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                _call0\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                 [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                  [J]com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                   [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                    [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                     [J]com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                      [J]java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset()Z\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                       [J]java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                        [J]com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$$Lambda$2.run()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                         [j]com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.lambda$createResourceFactory$414()V[clinit]\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                          [J]com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.lambda$createResourceFactory$414()V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                           [j]com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.getDefaultResourceFactory()Lcom/sun/prism/ResourceFactory;[clinit]\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                            [J]com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.getDefaultResourceFactory()Lcom/sun/prism/ResourceFactory;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                             [J]com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.getDefaultResourceFactory(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/sun/prism/ResourceFactory;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                              [J]com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.findDefaultResourceFactory(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/sun/prism/es2/ES2ResourceFactory;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                               [J]com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.getES2ResourceFactory(ILcom/sun/glass/ui/Screen;)Lcom/sun/prism/es2/ES2ResourceFactory;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                [J]com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.<init>(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Screen;)V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                 [J]com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Context.<init>(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Screen;Lcom/sun/prism/ps/ShaderFactory;)V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                  [J]com.sun.prism.es2.IOSGLFactory.createGLContext(Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLDrawable;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLPixelFormat;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLContext;Z)Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLContext;\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                   [J]com.sun.prism.es2.IOSGLContext.<init>(Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLDrawable;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLPixelFormat;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLContext;Z)V\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                    [J]com.sun.prism.es2.IOSGLContext.nInitialize(JJJZ)J\  
1.36 KB      13.4%  5                                     Java_com_sun_prism_es2_IOSGLContext_nInitialize\  
1.08 KB      10.6%  4                                      strdup\  
1.08 KB      10.6%  4                                       malloc\  
 288 Bytes    2.7%  1                                      malloc\
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer, but why bother? https://robovm.com/robovm-winding-down/

Comment: Hahahah @DerekJohnson Maybe you are right! But I don't know if this issue is related to RoboVM, Gluon or JavaFXPorts...

Comment: You can probably check by using the OpenJDK backend if it's available I haven't really followed gluon once I decided on a different path. But does it really matter? The OpenJDK port is based on an interpreter, AFAIK avian is in maintenance mode (and wasn't very performant to begin with) without a performant VM gluon doesn't make much sense. The task of maintaining FX, scene builder, IDE integration etc. is huge, add to that building a VM... They are smart people but everyone has a limit.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we have filed an issue and we'll look into it.